# Have a subfolder not controlled by wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress installed on the root of my website (say example.com/), but there is a folder of the website that i want to directly build in php/html not controlled by wordpress - basically I want it to be its own separate entity, but with the url being example.com/folder/, so it sits under wordpress in the url hierarchy, but is completely independant... Is that possible? I have done some research but cant find a solution or any reference to this.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the folder in the root directory of the wordpress install. Any files inside of that folder that does not declare the `wp-load.php` file will not be controlled by wordpress.